# Por que não consigo pegar os dados da form?

Tags: angularjs, html5

algo muuuuito estranho ta acontecendo, primeira vez que isso acontece.
Tenho um formulário de cadastro. quando clico em salvar, no console aparece 'undefined' e alinha... Impossível ser 'undefined' pois existem dados preenchidos!!! Vejam abaixo:

HTML

```
<form name="formAddress" ng-controller="InicialCtrl">
    <label>Nome do estabelecimento</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="name" mg-model="estabele.nome">

    <label>CEP</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="cep" mg-model="estabele.cep">

    <label>Endereço</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="address" mg-model="estabele.and" >

    <label>Cidade</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="city" mg-model="estabele.cidade" >

    <label>UF</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="uf" mg-model="estabele.uf" >

    <label>Contato</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="phone" mg-model="estabele.telefone">

    <button class="btn btn-block btn-primary btnRegister" ng-click="cadastro(estabele)">Cadastrar</button>
</form>
```

controller:

```
app.controller("InicialCtrl", ['$scope', '$http', '$window', '$location', '$rootScope', function ($scope, $http, $window, $location, $rootScope) {

$scope.cadastro = function(estabele){
    console.log(estabele);
}

}]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Porque você esta usando `mg-model` invés de `ng-model`.

Comment: É mesmo velho... Valeu... Acho que de tanto escrever essas diretivas, a gente escreve tão rápido que não se dá conta quando escrevemos errado e depois nos matamos para encontrar o problema achando que está tudo certo e não olhamos as coisas mais óbvias kkkkk
Abraçõo.

Comment: Compartilho desses deslizes hahahaha